# REACT: Instead of sorting by clicking a button - sorting by clicking header "id" in table

Tags: reactjs

I make request to server and I get response. Response it data which I display in view table-list. Also now I try implement when I click button `changeAsc` happen sort by `asc-desc`.

But I need that sort by asc-desc was happening when I click on header header `id` in table. And display the word `asc` or `desc` to the right of the header `id`.
 Table I export in file **Home.js** from file - **Table.js**.

What I need to change in file `Table.js` that implement sort when I click to header `id`?

## Home.js:

```
import Table from "./Table/Table.js";    

const Home = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    listCategory: [],     
    sortAscDesc: "asc",
  });
   
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(sortAscDesc) {
        const res = await api('api/categories', sortAscDesc);
          /....
    }
    fetchData(value.sortAscDesc); 
  }, [value.sortAscDesc]);

  const changeSortAscDesc = () => {    
      setValue((prev) => ({
       ...prev,
       sortAscDesc: prev.sortAscDesc == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc'
     }));
    }; 
    
  return (
    <div>
      
      <Table dataAttribute={value.listCategory}/>
    
      // I WANT DELETE THIS BUTTON:   - BECAUSE I WANT SORT BY HEADER "id"
      <button onClick={() => changeSortAscDesc()}>changeAsc</button>
     
   </div>
  );
};
```

## Table.js:

```
export default ({dataAttribute}) => (
  <table className="table">
    <thead className="table-head">
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>                  //I WANT SORT WHEN I CLICK ELEMENT id
        <th>title</th>
        <th>created_at</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {dataAttribute.map(item => (
        <tr key={item.id}>
          <td>{item.id}</td>
          <td>{item.title}</td>
          <td>{item.created_at}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
<Table dataAttribute={value.listCategory} changeSortAscDesc={changeSortAscDesc} />
```

In your Table.js

```
export default (props) => (
  <table className="table">
    <thead className="table-head">
      <tr>
        <th onClick={props.changeSortAscDesc}>id</th>                  //I want sort when I click by element id
        <th>title</th>
        <th>created_at</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {props.dataAttribute.map(item => (
          <tr key={item.id}>
          <td>{item.id}</td>
          <td>{item.title}</td>
          <td>{item.created_at}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);
```

Comment: Error: `'props' is not defined  no-undef`
in this line: `<th onClick={props.changeSortAscDesc}>id</th> `

Comment: You need import changeSortAscDesc as props like you're doing with dataAttribute. I have updated my answer. Please give it a try.